# Should i change the url in payment gateways after adding the SSL on ecommerce website?

Tags: php, ssl, paypal, opencart

I'm using two payment gateways on opencart ecommerce website.

1. Paypal Payment gateway (Opencart `Paypal Standard Payement Gateway` )
2. Cybersource Payment Gateway

I didn't use SSL yet but now i'm going to add SSL due to the security purpose. I want to let know after adding the SSL, I will have to add `s` in url which i'm using in the payment gateway or not ?

example I added this kind of url in payment gateway for the response

http://www.example.com/...

But after SSL i should add `s` like below ?

https://www.example.com/...

Can any one guide me I will appreciate.

Comment: simple answer: yes :)

Comment: @Meiko For confirmation I will have to add `s` in the url

Comment: Please refer this link http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/opencart/setting-up-payment-gateways/how-to-enable-ssl-connection-in-opencart  for more information. This will tell you about how to configure ssl in website developed in open cart.